# HTML Test runner giving error to import stringIO even after importing it

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I'm using the following code to implement HTML test runner in my code:

```
import HtmlTestRunner
import unittest
from io import StringIO

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    """ Example test for HtmlRunner. """

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

    def test_isupper(self):
        self.assertTrue('FOO'.isupper())
        self.assertFalse('Foo'.isupper())

    def test_split(self):
        s = 'hello world'
        self.assertEqual(s.split(), ['hello', 'world'])
        # check that s.split fails when the separator is not a string
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            s.split(2)

    def test_error(self):
        """ This test should be marked as error one. """
        raise ValueError

    def test_fail(self):
        """ This test should fail. """
        self.assertEqual(1, 2)

    @unittest.skip("This is a skipped test.")
    def test_skip(self):
        """ This test should be skipped. """
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='test_dir'))
```

but getting the  following error:

> C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32‌​\python.exe C:/Users/inswadhwa/PycharmProjects/automation/assertion.py Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/inswadhwa/PycharmProjects/automation/assertion.py"‌​, line 2, in  import HTMLTestRunner File "C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-3‌​2\lib\HTMLTestRunner‌​.py", line 97, in  import StringIO ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'StringIO' Process finished with exit code 1

I have already imported `StringIO`.

Can anyone please suggest a way to overcome the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using [this library](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner.html), which [appears](http://tungwaiyip.info/software/HTMLTestRunner_0_8_2/HTMLTestRunner.py) not to have been updated to work with Python 3, where [the old `StringIO` module has been replaced with the `io.StringIO` class](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit).

Try using [`html-testRunner`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html-testRunner/1.0.3) instead. It should work with Python 3.

Comment: Thanks Chris html-testRunner helped me...but after running the suite I'm facing some isuue,the output in the console I'm getting while generating the report is:
   test_number = int(test_name.split('_')[1])
   IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Now, let's see if this is something simple. It looks like that library assumes your test names all contain an underscore. The ones in your listing above do; do you have any other tests that don't contain an underscore in their name?

Comment: Hey chris I have to ask you another question...can that question be made explicitly available to you because you have provided the most appropriate solution to me